# How to check validity of an address in solidity?

Tags: solidity, addresses

Here's a simple contract:

```
contract C {
    event myEvent(bool x, address y);
    address someAddress;

    function someAddressExist(){
        if(someAddress != 0){
            myEvent(true, someAddress);
        }
    }    

    function setSomeAddress(address y){
        someAddress = y;
    }
}
```

When I try to send a transaction to any address on the test network, except `0x1`, it works. What's so special about this address? Are there any other addresses like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure...what is your understanding of a valid address? In your example the argument you specify is a perfect valid address.

An address is just a variable that can hold a 20 byte value.

To answer the edited question of the OP I can link to this thread: [Not all addresses created equal?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8030/not-all-addresses-created-equal).
Basically some addresses hold some precompiled contracts so they will execute code if transactions are sent to them.

Comment: when I do `web3.isAddress('0x1')` is returns `false`. A bit confusing. I was thinking that maybe Solidity pads it to look like `0x10000000000000000000`, but it returns `0x1` in the log. I wonder if it's possible to do something like `address('0x1').send()`

Comment: Strange but `isAddress()` is not documented in the javascript api...you can see that in the solidity documents the type of address can be of.the form you mentioned http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html. And im still not sure what you understand by a valid address

Comment: well, to me a valid address is a 20 bytes HEX string which I can send transactions to. If I try to send some wei from inside the contractt using `address.send()` to `0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, it works, but if try to send to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001` as well as to `0x1` it doesn't work. What might be the problem here?

Comment: I think you got the answer in another thread :) If that is the case i will link that answer here

Answer (score 1):

```
web3.utils.isAddress(address)
```

Checks if a given string is a valid Ethereum address. It will also check the checksum, if the address has upper and lowercase letters.