# Not all addresses created equal?

Tags: addresses, precompiled-contracts

I'm using this code to send transactions in test network(Morden):

```
var transactionObject = {
    to: '**addresses are below**',  
    gasPrice: 22000000000,
    gas: 42000,
    value: 1
}
var callback = function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    else {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject, callback)
```

- **Address:** 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
- **Gas used:** 24000
- **Txhash:** 0x18e5810b87b2fc22f1e2493643d13c94510938a6c4f4b857fad8072e374ac63c
- **Additional:** Consumed more than usual gas. This is not a contract address.

---

- **Address:** 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002
- **Gas used:** 21060
- **Txhash:** 0xde9cc279c1a5e03915f202ddf3f1893d2f8ea9cd4c1baadf214ee4aaedb81390
- **Additional:** Consumed more than usual gas. This is not a contract address.

---

- **Address:** 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003
- **Gas used:** 21600
- **Txhash:** 0x6669cf3f54f727ca1485e104b691760e985e57cc2dc511218d124f3edf9f158a
- **Additional:** etherscan.io shows that this address received only one transaction(my transaction with value 1 wei), but the the balance of this address is 8 wei. How is that possible?

---

- **Address:** 0x4fdd50D0FFd2D430b0181a9c2882FEbc87b79F40
- **Gas used:** 21000
- **Txhash:** 0x8aee5c80edbc5fe8bbfef13a0693d6a4752a44443131597d960e95673b2e19cf
- **Additional:** Transaction to a normal looking address consumed a normal amount of gas.

---

Why do transactions to certain addresses(not contract addresses) consume more gas? I have a hunch that these addresses are used for something special. If so, where can I get the list of this special addresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) states:

> These are four so-called ‘precompiled’ contracts, meant as a
>   preliminary piece of architecture that may later become native
>   extensions. The four contracts in addresses 1, 2, 3 and 4 execute the
>   elliptic curve public key recovery function, the SHA2 256-bit hash
>   scheme, the RIPEMD 160-bit hash scheme and the identity function
>   respectively.

See [What's a precompiled contract and how are they different from native opcodes?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/440/whats-a-precompiled-contract-and-how-are-they-different-from-native-opcodes)

Thus, sending a transaction to addresses 1-4 is executing code and costs more gas.

Comment: Thank you very much, good sir!!! I wouldn't have figured it out in a million blocks!